# Floating menu on top of all apps

Tags: java, android, user-interface, interface, floating

I want to make a menu floating above all applications.
I did see this question: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

 
but I want it to be functional in ICS too.

 There is an app, GameCIH, that has such an interface, supporting touch in ICS:
[image]

How is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: System level alert window/dialog? [permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Comment: No! I want something like the picture, the bar under the notification bar. This is why I gave the link to the question, it talks about something else. it talks about a working UI, on top of any other app (other apps still function normally), but the problem it is not supported in ICS and above

Comment: GameCIH (Google play gives one app in search: CheatEngine) uses SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. So I guess they do it this way.

Comment: I know how to make it look like this, but I can't make it handle clicks (It should be a service, so that other apps runnning below it will still be functional.